# Mapbox-GL Unable to Load Satellite Map on Android/iOS with Ionic and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I had to revert back to Mapbox-GL v2.15.0 because I was getting WebGL errors on the Android Emulator, but the behavior I'm seeing now is consistent between iOS and Android.

When I try to load a page on either an iOS or Android device that contains a Mapbox-GL map using the satellite view I receive errors saying:

> Could not load image because of The source image could not be
> decoded.. Please make sure to use a supported image type such as PNG
> or JPEG. Note that SVGs are not supported.

Code from page.ts file:

```
let style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9';

this.mapbox = new mapboxgl.Map({
    accessToken: environment.mapbox.accessToken,
    container: 'mapbox',
    style: style,
    zoom: 10,
    center: [97.733330, 30.266666],
});
```